# How can we get records in single row in SQL server using SQL/TSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

-- Source

```
Create table staging
(id int,
 name varchar(50),
 empid int,
 company_id int,
 addres varchar(50)
)

Create table Destination
(id int,
 name varchar(50),
 empid int,
 company_id int,
 addres varchar(50)
)

insert into staging
select 1, 'amit',NULL,101,'USA'
UNION ALL
Select 1,'amit',10002,'','USA'
UNION ALL
Select 2,'Vijay','',650,'China'
UNION ALL
Select 2,'Vijay','','','China'
UNION ALL
Select 5,'Sanjay',589756,NULL,'India'
UNION ALL
Select 5,'Sanjay',NULL,151215,'India'


Select * from staging
```

-- Expected result

--  Destination table

```
id  name    empid   company_id  addres
1   amit    10002   101         USA
2   Vijay   0       650         China
5   Sanjay  589756  151215      India
```

Comment: Please, edit your question by adding the expected result.

Comment: It would look like `GROUP BY` is the solution, though the question is if, for instance, you may have a record like `1,'amit',44444,'','USA'`.

Answer (score 1):

Use **Group By** and **MAX**

```
insert into destination
select id, max(name), max(empid), max(company_id), max(addres) from staging
group by id
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: It will be time consuming there are  3 Min rows in staging